# Anyone have a better color picker?

Tags: android, colors, dialog, android-widget, color-picker

Most color pickers out there (Such as the API demo, CWAC-Colormixer, and other freebies) just let you pick a color and offer few or no supporting features, such as

- History of previously chosen colors
- HEX display of color selected.
- Palette of common color constants (white, black, blue, red, etc.)

I could develop these myself, but thought I'd ask first if someone already knows of any existing color picking dialogs with advanced features?

Comment: Appears OpenIntents color picker has a history option, none of the other mentioned features though... http://www.openintents.org/en/colorpicker and http://www.openintents.org/en/node/670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not cover every feature mentioned, but definitely hits many I did not: Keith's UberColorPicker is chalk full of features and far more powerful than the API demo or any other open source color picker I've seen.

Demo: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keithwiley.android.ubercolorpickerdemo

Source: http://keithwiley.com/Downloads/AndroidUberColorPickerDemo.zip

EDIT: Word of warning though, it does not use layouts and can be a bear to adapt.